# Prevent body scrolling with fixed position div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

I have a dropdown menu that overflows the screen height on mobile, and I would like to make it scrollable, however, I am facing a problem with the body behind the sticky positioned element also scrolling, causing issues with having to scroll almost the entire body before you can scroll to the bottom part of the dropdown menu.

A suggestion I've seen from another post was to apply a class with `overflow: hidden` to the body, when the dropdown menu is toggled, you can see with `.body_overflow` I attempted this, I have also tried setting `.body_overflow` to a div containing everything else in the body below `#market_menu`, however, applying `.body_overflow` to `body` prevented any scrolling, even with `overflow: scroll` applied to `#mm_dropdown` and `market_menu`, and applying `.body_overflow` to a div containing all elements below `#market_menu` in the body, did nothing at all.

The JS you see below is applying `.show` to `#mm_dropdown` when `#markets_button` is toggled, I was also using it to apply `.body_overflow` to the body and the div containing everything below the menu.

HTML:

```
<div id="market_menu" class="black">
    <button onclick="dropMenu()" id="markets_button">Markets</button>
    <div id="mm_dropdown" class="mm_dropdown">
      <a href="" id="mm_active_child">Line 1</a>
      <a href="">Line 2</a>
      <a href="">Line 3</a>
      <a href="">Line 4</a>
      <a href="">Line 5</a>
      <a href="">Line 6</a>
      <a href="">Line 7</a>
      <a href="">Line 8</a>
      <a href="">Line 9</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#market_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#market_menu button {
    height: 75px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.mm_dropdown {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#market_menu a {
    display: flex;
    height: 75px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
#market_menu a:hover {
     color: white;
     background-color: black;
 }
#mm_active_child {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 865px) {
    #market_menu {
        top: 7rem;
    }
    .mm_dropdown {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    #market_menu a {
        padding: 0 14pt;
    }
    #market_menu button {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 865px) {
    #market_menu {
        top: 5rem;
    }
    .mm_dropdown {
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        display: none;
    }
    #market_menu button {
        display: flex;
    }
}
.show {
    display: flex;
}
.body_overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function dropMenu() {
            document.getElementById("mm_dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
            document.getElementById("market_body").classList.toggle("body_overflow")
            console.log("click");
        }

        // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('#markets_button')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementById("mm_dropdown");
                var body = document.getElementById("market_body");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    var overflowBody = body[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                    if (overflowBody.classList.contains('body_overflow')) {
                        overflowBody.classList.remove('body_overflow');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Nothing is `fixed` position in given code. Please read  [mcve]

Comment: @TJ my mistake, I meant `sticky`, will make appropriate edits

Answer (score 0):

Can you make an if statement that detects if the button was click to style the body to stuck? If you want, I'll show you how thats done.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your menu doesn't have a scroll of it's own is because it doesn't have a height of it's own. Once you give it a height (`height: 50vh;`), menu items will scroll within.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropMenu() {
  document.getElementById("mm_dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  //document.getElementById("market_body").classList.toggle("body_overflow")
  console.log("click");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#markets_button')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementById("mm_dropdown");
    var body = document.getElementById("market_body");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      var overflowBody = body[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
      if (overflowBody.classList.contains('body_overflow')) {
        overflowBody.classList.remove('body_overflow');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#market_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#market_menu button {
  height: 75px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mm_dropdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#market_menu a {
  display: flex;
  height: 75px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

#market_menu a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#mm_active_child {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 865px) {
  #market_menu {
    top: 7rem;
  }
  .mm_dropdown {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  #market_menu a {
    padding: 0 14pt;
  }
  #market_menu button {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 865px) {
  #market_menu {
    top: 5rem;
  }
  .mm_dropdown {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    display: none;
  }
  #market_menu button {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.body_overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="market_menu" class="black">
  <button onclick="dropMenu()" id="markets_button">Markets</button>
  <div id="mm_dropdown" class="mm_dropdown">
    <a href="" id="mm_active_child">Line 1</a>
    <a href="">Line 2</a>
    <a href="">Line 3</a>
    <a href="">Line 4</a>
    <a href="">Line 5</a>
    <a href="">Line 6</a>
    <a href="">Line 7</a>
    <a href="">Line 8</a>
    <a href="">Line 9</a>
  </div>
</div>
```